# Binding RichText with multiple children into SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter

I have a piece of text which requires certain words to be bold (Headings, etc.). I usually use a `RichText` with multiple `TextSpan` to format the text the way I want it, but that doesn't scroll.

So I used a `SingleChildScrollView` but is there any way of formatting text in a `SingleChildScrollView` or do I have to use another widget to scroll the text.

Here is an example of the SingleChildScrollView I'm using:

```
// Publications
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Publications"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new Text(
            'Federation\n\n //Need this to be bold'
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\n\n'
                '\n\nEditor', // Need this to be bold
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "that doesn't scroll" ?

Comment: One can only see the text which can be fit on the device display, any more text won't be visible as it won't scroll. I can post a snippet of code for that as well.

Comment: Indeed. In the end that's what you want to do. Not using `Text`

Comment: I believe the post above could've been phrased better, I need to allow the text to scroll as the content of the text is on the higher side and won't fit on a single screen without scroll. At the same time, I need certain headings to be bold. This won't work when using 'Text', I need to find a way to bind 'RichText' to a 'SingleChildScrollView' or find another way to make 'RichText' scrollable.

Comment: What kind rendering do you expect ? Text wrap ? Horizontal scroll ? Horizontal scroll but heading stay visible ?

Comment: Vertical Scroll, heading doesn't have to stay visible

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `TextStyle` you can add `fontWeight: FontWeight.bold` to make your text bold.

For example you have:

```
style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
```

Just add like this:

```
style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
```

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't that make the changes to the whole text. For example, if I need something in bold followed by a regular text: **Heading** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Comment: You are right, sorry about that kind of rushed to answer